# How can I access a Widget of a window from another window?

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, widget

I have two "Forms" with related .cpp files: mainwindow.cpp and settings.cpp

I have a label "TitleLabel" in "MainWindow" that I want to modify when I push a button in "Settings".

The files are structured like this (I removed most of the non-relevant code to simplify):

```
//MainWindow
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "settings.h"


//...

void MainWindow::on_Settings_clicked() //Opens settings
{
    Settings settings;
    settings.setModal(true);
    settings.exec();
}
```

and Settings:

```
//Settings
#include "settings.h"
#include "ui_settings.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

//...

void Settings::on_ChangeMain_clicked()
{
//what to do here?
}
```

Firstly I tried to do it like this:

```
void Settings::on_ChangeMain_clicked()
{
MainWindow.ui->TitleLabel->setText("OK");
}
```

But it gives me a Syntax error that I cannot solve, roughly translated to:

```
\settings.cpp:75: error: C2143: syntax error: ';' missing before '.'
```

I tried adding a ';' before the '.' but it still gives me the same error.

Then I tried making a pointer to the MainWindow and use that, like this:

```
    void Settings::on_ChangeMain_clicked()
    {
   MainWindow *mw = new MainWindow();
   mw->ui->TitleLabel->setText("OK");
    }
```

This time it tells me that it's impossible to access a private member of the class MainWindow. I don't know if I should or even how to give the permissions to Settings to access those members. I feel really lost, what should I do?

**EDIT :**
I was able to solve this problem by using Qt's SIGNALs and SLOTs.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585050/how-to-share-share-widgets-pointers-with-another-widgets and a lot of other related questions

Comment: @SaZ Thanks, so I guess I should learn to use Signals and slots.

Comment: First: learn some OOP basics.

Comment: @SaZ I thought I understood them enough, but evidently I need to go over them again.

Comment: I think that sharing 1 variable between 2 classes - is programming basic. And I found a lot of similar questions with answers on stackoverflow. You should start with search and research, instead of asking such common things. See this article: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @SaZ I found a solution. Should I tag the post as "solved" somehow, or close it?

Comment: You may answer your own quetion and accept it in one day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may to do something like this:

Define public slot in MainWindow:

```
void MainWindow::slotChangeLabel(const QString str)
{
    label->setText(str);
}
```

Define singal and slot in Settings:

```
class Settings : public QWidget, private Ui::Settings
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Settings(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:
    void changeLabel(const QString);


public slots:
    void clickBtn();
};
```

Slot should handle something like this:

```
    void Settings::clickBtn()
{
    emit changeLabel("Ok");
}
```

And don't forget connect signal and slot for button at Settings widget:

```
Settings::Settings(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    ...
    connect(pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(clickBtn()));
}
```

After all connect signal and slot for this Settings and MainWindow widgets at `main()`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;    
    Settings s;

    QObject::connect(&s, SIGNAL(changeLabel(const QString)), &w, SLOT(slotChangeLabel(const QString)));

    s.show();
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is pretty much what I did to solve the problem.